# Console App using entity, can i use the same connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, connection-string

In order to run scheduled task related to our MVC web application, we took the following decision:

Lets make a new C# console app that uses Entity framework, FTP, And SMTP. And this application is going to be runned by the task manager on the server. This way, it could be runned outside browsers.

After adding all the references in the console app, i copied the Entity connection string in the WEB project :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=srv-sql-prod2;  initial catalog=Institutions; User ID=qwerty; Password=qwerty;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And i pasted it in the App.config of the console app. I thought it would be able to use the same `edmx` file that the web app uses. But here's how i would translate the error :

> Exeption type: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> An exeption has been raised by the type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig'.

Do i have to create another edmx file inside my console app ? Can it work otherwise ?

Comment: Well if it's not a good question, can downvoters at least explain me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are bypassing the wizard to create a model from the database and are instead copying the connection string over from the your web app and hoping for some build magic.

Try using the wizard referenced in the link below and start at step 3. Reverse Engineer the Model.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

Comment: The `edmx` file is in a separated project and i can see both projects in my solution explorer, but i guess i have to create the edmx file in the new project